# Using Dropbox with multiple cameras

Tags: dropbox

I have a problem with Dropbox Camera Upload: I have an iPad, an iPhone and a Samsung Galaxy Camera, all uploading photos to Dropbox. I would like to create different folders for each one of them: `uploads from iPad`, `uploads from iPhone`, `uploads from Samsung`, to divide the photos from each device. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't see anything in any of the settings either on Dropbox via the web or in the Android app to identify the device used. But then, I don't see such a setting in any of the other instant upload services (Google+ Instant Upload, Facebook Instant Upload, Carbonite) that I looked at either.

Comment: I assume you want to automate the sorting process, right? If not, you can certainly create the folders and sort them manually (and in bulk)

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** no application has this feature but you can do it yourself (if you know how),

Those clients (be it Dropbox, Google or Facebook) just didn't implement this feature while it is technically possible.

You'll have to add a post-upload hook to read the info from the picture to categorize your uploads. These providers usually provides API to access your data to facilitate this, enabling services like [ifttt.com](https://ifttt.com).

You can also do it locally use some scripting language Python/Ruby/Node.js to monitor `Dropbox\Camera Uploads` and do the categorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating separate folders in DropBox folder and then configuring Camera applications on your devices to store all pictures in the specific folder. However, I am not sure if all the devices and applications you use will have this configuration option.